# Where is the Ravager's head?

Tags: mass-effect-3

In ME3, the Ravager doesn't have a clearly defined head. For headshot bonus, where is the Ravager's head? Is it the blue circle on the front?

[image]

Comment: The circle is the former Rachni's head. Not sure if it takes extra damage or not, but it seems like it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Due to some poor decision making, I've played a Soldier in each game, so I've had to learn where the exploitable weak points are for the various enemies. Not having any biotic or tech skills always put me at a slight disadvantage, so I had to take extra care to find the weaknesses.

Think of that circle as a bulls-eye. It *is* considered the weak point for the Ravager.

Be careful when firing at it, though. If you hit the fleshy sac below, it will release Swarmers. They're extremely weak, but can become a nuisance in large numbers.